# Is it possible to merge iterators in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, iteration

Is it possible to merge iterators in Java? I have two iterators and I want to combine/merge them so that I could iterate though their elements in one go (in same loop) rather than two steps. Is that possible?

Note that the number of elements in the two lists can be different therefore one loop over both lists is not the solution.

```
Iterator<User> pUsers = userService.getPrimaryUsersInGroup(group.getId());
Iterator<User> sUsers = userService.getSecondaryUsersInGroup(group.getId());

while(pUsers.hasNext()) {
  User user = pUsers.next();
  .....
}

while(sUsers.hasNext()) {
  User user = sUsers.next();
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 55):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) (formerly Google Collections) has [Iterators.concat](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)).

Comment: There appears to be no way to get that second link working properly :(

Comment: @youssef @Colin: The intent of the link is to go to the `concat()` method immediately without scrolling (using the `#` hash fragment). That part was however not correctly URL-encoded. I fixed it (long live Firefox with automagic URL-encoding when copypasting links from its address bar).

Comment: Hmm interesting. Though cannot use it as we aren't using Guava in our software.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, and he originally had the URL basically the same as you have it now.

Comment: @Jahanzeb Farooq Well you should be! =) That said, obviously that's often not a decision you can just make yourself.

Comment: I think Iterators.concat is useful for small collections, but not Iterables which access databases. The concat method converts first all given iterators into an array list and then returns it iterator. The Commons Collections seem to work with less memory, as it does not convert it to an ArrayList, but keeps both iterators untouched, until it is necessary. Please be aware of this behaviour!

Comment: @guerda: You're mistaken. Iterators.concat is lazy; it doesn't buffer elements in a list.

Comment: @David: Are you sure? I assumed it because of this implementation: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java?r=9dcde66ab9bfcdbe007b69d4912a297894bece59#524

Comment: @guerda: Yes. The code you're referring to creates an array _of iterators_; it doesn't have anything to do with the contents of those iterators.

Answer (score 21):

Also the [Apache Commons Collection](http://commons.apache.org/collections) have several classes for manipulating Iterators, like the [IteratorChain](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/IteratorChain.html), that wraps a number of Iterators.

Comment: I think this method is less resource intensive, as it does not convert all iterators to an ArrayList.

Comment: The javadoc on the guava one currently mentiones explicitly that the concatenated iterators are not polled until necessary.

Answer (score 19):

You could create your own implementation of the `Iterator` interface which iterates over the iterators:

```
public class IteratorOfIterators implements Iterator {
    private final List<Iterator> iterators;

    public IteratorOfIterators(List<Iterator> iterators) {
        this.iterators = iterators;
    }

    public IteratorOfIterators(Iterator... iterators) {
        this.iterators = Arrays.asList(iterators);
    }


    public boolean hasNext() { /* implementation */ }

    public Object next() { /* implementation */ }

    public void remove() { /* implementation */ }
}
```

*(I've not added generics to the Iterator for brevity.)* The implementation is not too hard, but isn't the most trivial, you need to keep track of which `Iterator` you are currently iterating over, and calling `next()` you'll need to iterate as far as you can through the iterators until you find a `hasNext()` that returns `true`, or you may hit the end of the last iterator.

<strike>I'm not aware of any implementation that already exists for this.</strike>

*Update:*
I've up-voted [Andrew Duffy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610261/is-it-possible-to-merge-iterators-in-java/3610310#3610310) answer - no need to re-invent the wheel. I really need to look into Guava in more depth.

I've added another constructor for a variable number of arguments - almost getting off topic, as how the class is constructed here isn't really of interest, just the concept of how it works.

Answer (score 14):

I haven't written Java code in a while, and this got me curious to whether I've still "got it".

First try:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Arrays; /* For sample code */

public class IteratorIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final Iterator<T> is[];
    private int current;

    public IteratorIterator(Iterator<T>... iterators)
    {
            is = iterators;
            current = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
            while ( current < is.length && !is[current].hasNext() )
                    current++;

            return current < is.length;
    }

    public T next() {
            while ( current < is.length && !is[current].hasNext() )
                    current++;

            return is[current].next();
    }

    public void remove() { /* not implemented */ }

    /* Sample use */
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
            Iterator<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4).iterator();
            Iterator<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(10,11,12).iterator();
            Iterator<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(99, 98, 97).iterator();

            Iterator<Integer> ii = new IteratorIterator<Integer>(a,b,c);

            while ( ii.hasNext() )
                    System.out.println(ii.next());
    }
}
```

You *could* of course use more Collection classes rather than a pure array + index counter, but this actually feels a bit cleaner than the alternative. Or am I just biased from writing mostly C these days?

Anyway, there you go. The answer to you question is "yes, probably".

Answer (score 9):

```
public class IteratorJoin<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final Iterator<T> first, next;

    public IteratorJoin(Iterator<T> first, Iterator<T> next) {
        this.first = first;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return first.hasNext() || next.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (first.hasNext())
            return first.next();
        return next.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Java 8 and later this can be done without external dependencies using [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-). This also allows concatenation of iterator with other types of streams.

```java
Streams.concat(
   StreamSupport.stream(<iter1>, false), 
   StreamSupport.stream(<iter2>, false));
```

Answer (score 5):

move your loop to a method and pass the iterator to method.

```
void methodX(Iterator x) {
    while (x.hasNext()) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still have to call the method twice.

Comment: This seems to me to be the simplest solution (without Guava) for your specific case. Yes you have to call methodX twice but you'd have to  make two method calls anyway, one to merge the iterators, and one to do what methodX does.

Your own solution with the flag seems more complicated and probably more code.

Answer (score 4):

an iterator comes FROM a collection or a set.
why not use the method already available
`Collection.addAll(Collection c);`
and then create your iterator from the last object.
this way, your iterator will iterate all the contents of both collection.

Comment: This has some drawbacks, in particular if you want to use lazy iterators or if the collections are very large.

Comment: So many reasons not to use this. Iterators don't have to come from a collection or set. Even if they did, you shouldn't copy all those references unless you know you'll go through them all.

Comment: It does not necessarily come from a collection, go back to the basics, an iterator is anything able to iterate and doesn't need to be a collection, they call it abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [my version](https://gist.github.com/reutsharabani/03a457b401b81e448ce2) of an extendable iterator. It uses a double-ended queue of iterators which to me makes sense:

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque;

public class ExtendableIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    public Deque<Iterator<T>> its = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Iterator<T>>();

    public ExtendableIterator() {

    }

    public ExtendableIterator(Iterator<T> it) {
        this();
        this.extend(it);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // this is true since we never hold empty iterators
        return !its.isEmpty() && its.peekLast().hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        T next = its.peekFirst().next();
        if (!its.peekFirst().hasNext()) {
            its.removeFirst();
        }
        return next;
    }

    public void extend(Iterator<T> it) {
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            its.addLast(it);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Merged Iterator:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class ConcatIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final List<Iterable<T>> iterables;
    private Iterator<T> current;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ConcatIterator(final Iterable<T>... iterables) {
        this.iterables = new LinkedList<>(asList(iterables));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        checkNext();
        return current != null && current.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        checkNext();
        if (current == null || !current.hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return current.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if (current == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        current.remove();
    }

    private void checkNext() {
        while ((current == null || !current.hasNext()) && !iterables.isEmpty()) {
            current = iterables.remove(0).iterator();
        }
    }

}
```

The `concat` method to create an `Iterable`:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Iterable<T> concat(final Iterable<T>... iterables) {
    return () -> new ConcatIterator<>(iterables);
}
```

Simple JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testConcat() throws Exception {
    final Iterable<Integer> it1 = asList(1, 2, 3);
    final Iterable<Integer> it2 = asList(4, 5);
    int j = 1;
    for (final int i : concat(it1, it2)) {
        assertEquals(j, i);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the List returned by Arrays.asList() directly, instead of the LinkedList? Because of the possible changes in the array "iterables"? Is this something I have to be worried about, even without multithreading? I would have to rewiev some of my code...

Comment: @NicStray the `LinkedList` here is only used to make a defensive copy, which will iterate over the elements. it's a design choice. you may chose to use `asList(..)` directly and avoid the copy operations, but then you must ensure not to modify the original iterables before using the `Iterator`. the choice is yours...

Comment: @NicStray the copy constructor of the `LinkedList` here is called. if you want to use `asList(..)` directly, you need to have an index variable or otherwise change the code, since remove will not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor the original design from:

```
Iterator<User> pUsers = userService.getPrimaryUsersInGroup(group.getId());
Iterator<User> sUsers = userService.getSecondaryUsersInGroup(group.getId());
```

To something like:

```
Iterator<User> users = userService.getUsersInGroup(group.getId(), User.PRIMARY, User.SECONDARY, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`ConcatIterator`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.10/org/cactoos/list/ConcatIterator.html) from [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
Iterator<String> names = new ConcatIterator<>(
  Arrays.asList("Sarah", "Mary").iterator(),
  Arrays.asList("Jeff", "Johnny").iterator(),
);
```

Also check [`ConcatIterable`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.10/org/cactoos/list/ConcatIterable.html), which concatenates `Iterable`s.

Comment: The last comma must be removed

Answer (score 1):

In the [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) there is [`public static <E> Iterator<E> org.apache.commons.collections4.IteratorUtils.chainedIterator(Collection<Iterator<? extends E>> iterators)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils.html#chainedIterator-java.util.Collection-) that says

> Gets an iterator that iterates through a collections of Iterators one after another.

which should be what you want.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.IteratorUtils;
//also works: import org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils;

class Scratch {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        final Iterator<String> combinedIterator = IteratorUtils.chainedIterator(
                Arrays.asList( "a", "b", "c" ).iterator(),
                Arrays.asList( "1", "2", "3" ).iterator()
            );
        while( combinedIterator.hasNext() ){
            System.out.println( combinedIterator.next() );
        }
        // "abc123" will have been printed out
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

every `Iterator` object holds own memory location (**adress**), so you can't simply "merge" them. except if you extend `iterator` class and write your own implementation there.

If you are dealing with the **same number of objects** in both iterators an alternative solution  would be to process two iterators in one loop like this :

```
   while (iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext()) {
      // code
    }
```

Comment: OP does not necessarily need to iterate both at once. He is looking more to iterate one, then the other. Your second solution will fail once the first iterator has been processed.