# Iterating through multiple lists using single for-each loop in java

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, java-7

I have multiple lists created like below

```
static List<String> dbName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> dbServerName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> lDbName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> lServerName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> serverName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> dbServerNameSecondary = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is it possible to iterate over all the list objects using a single for-each loop
like below

for (items in dbName,dbServerName....)

I would like to iterate parallely and put the values obtained in the below query

String drop = "Drop table if exists "+hive_db+"."+"IB_C3_"+dbName+"_"+dbServerName;

Comment: If they have the same length, you could make for loop, where you would increase index nummber and inside loop get each element.

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Effectively a concatenation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join multiple iterators in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200080/join-multiple-iterators-in-java)

Comment: Is there a reason why not to represent the the DB object as a simple class with attributes such as dbServerName then have one list of DB objects

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *assuming the lists are all the same size*, you can iterate them in *parallel* by using a standard `for` loop:

```
static List<String> dbName = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> dbServerName = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> lDbName = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> lServerName = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> serverName = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> dbServerNameSecondary = new ArrayList<String>();

// code filling lists here

for (int i = 0; i < dbName.size(); i++) {
    // dbName.get(i)
    // ...
    // dbServerNameSecondary.get(i)
}
```

However, if the lists are the same size, then using the Object-Oriented features of Java is **strongly** recommended. This means creating a class for the values.

```
public class Database {
    private String dbName;
    private String dbServerName;
    private String lDbName;
    private String lServerName;
    private String serverName;
    private String dbServerNameSecondary;
    // getters and setters here
}

static List<Database> databases = new ArrayList<>();

// code filling list here

for (Database database : databases) {
    // database.getDbName()
    // ...
    // database.getDbServerNameSecondary()
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to have a concatenation of the values rather than parallel iteration. But the second point is certainly valid - storing an `Object` in parallel arrays is a sure sign of object phobia...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Perhaps. Question is unclear on that point. The other answer shows how to do that, so between this and that, OP's need should be covered.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would like to do parallel iteration than concatenation

Comment: @dataEnthusiast I would **strongly** suggest you go with the `Object` based solution in this answer in that case. If those are indeed parallel arrays then that is completely non-OO.