# Merging multiple hashmaps

Tags: java, dictionary, merge, hashmap

So, i have two hashMaps

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

public HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

I want to create a hashmap, which consists of both of these hashmaps merged.

Also, when I add an element to either of these 2 hashmaps:

```
map1.put("key",1);
```

The third hashmap should have this change

**SOLUTION:**

```
import java.util.*;
public final class JoinedMap {
static class JoinedMapView<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {
    private final Map<? extends K,? extends V>[] items;
    public JoinedMapView(final Map<? extends K,? extends V>[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int ct = 0;
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            ct += map.size();
        }
        return ct;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            if(map.isEmpty()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            if(map.containsKey(key)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            if(map.containsValue(value)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            if(map.containsKey(key)){
                return map.get(key);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            map.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        Set<K> mrgSet = new HashSet<K>();
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            mrgSet.addAll(map.keySet());
        }
        return mrgSet;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        Collection<V> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Map<? extends K,? extends V> map : items) {
            values.addAll(map.values());
        }
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a live aggregated map view of the maps passed in.
 * None of the above methods is thread safe (nor would there be an easy way
 * of making them).
 */
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> combine(
        final Map<? extends K, ? extends V>... items) {
    return new JoinedMapView<K,V>(items);
}

private JoinedMap() {
}
}
```

Comment: @andras That is not the exact duplicate. The issue here is different. Please read the question clearly before closing it as duplicate.

Comment: I want the third map to have any changes i make to the first 2 maps though. This wouldn't do it

Comment: sorry, did not notice the extra requirement. the clarification helps.

Comment: Do you mean from [`Guava`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat%28java.util.Iterator,%20java.util.Iterator%29)? It allows you to traverse both collections in one loop.  I believe it does not actually create the third one.

Comment: What happens if both map1 and map2 have keyX? What happens when you do mergedMap.put(KeyNooneElseHas)?

Comment: At least a partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610261/is-it-possible-to-merge-iterators-in-java

Comment: Can you explain what do you try to achieve? Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: @mlk raises some interesting issues. What you probably want is to provide a "view" of the two maps, not an other map that you have to maintain if anything happens to either maps. Guava `Iterators.concat` might be a step in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this kind of approach is a good start (of course you would need to override HashMap's remove and other appropriate methods):

```
class MyMergeAwareHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    HashMap<K, V> mergeMap

    public MyMergeAwareHashMap(Map<K, V> mergeMap) {
      this.mergeMap = mergeMap
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(K key, V value) {
      super.put(key, value)
      mergeMap.put(key, value)
    }
}

HashMap<String, Integer> mergedMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
MyMergeAwareHashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new MyMergeAwareHashMap<String, Integer>(mergedMap)
MyMergeAwareHashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new MyMergeAwareHashMap<String, Integer>(mergedMap)


map1.put('A', 1)
map2.put('B', 2)

println(map1.get('A')) // => 1
println(map1.get('B')) // => null

println(map2.get('A')) // => null
println(map2.get('B')) // => 2

println(mergedMap.get('A')) // => 1
println(mergedMap.get('B')) // => 2
```

Comment: Strangely this does not work in groovy web console anymore but works when I run it locally.

Comment: Thank you! This is an easy way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to manually update your 3rd map, you need a wrapper, extending hashmap for it

```
public class ExtHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K,V>{

    HashMap<K,V> map1,map2;

    public ExtHashMap(HashMap<k,V> _map1, HashMap<K,V> _map2){
       map1=_map1;
       map2=_map2;
    }

    //then override every method simulating merged map1,map2
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) { /* find in map1 or map2*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one map and filter the retrieved data based on the map you want to read from.
It really depends on how you want to treat collisions between two maps. If you want no collisions you can use:

```
private Map<String, Integer> map = newHashMap<>():

void putInMap1(String key, Integer value) {
    map.put(key + "_1", value);
}

void putInMap2(String key, Integer value) {
    map.put(key + "_" + 1, value);
}

Integer getFromMap1(String key) {
     return map.get(key + "_1");
}

Integer getFromMap2(String key) {
     return map.get(key + "_2");
}

List<Integer> getFromMap3(String key) {
     List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
     Integer map1Val = getFromMap1(key);
     if (map1Val != null) {
        res.add(map1Val);
     }
     Integer map2Val = getFromMap2(key);
     if (map2Val != null) {
        res.add(map2Val);
     }
     return res;
}
```