# Extracting map values in multiple braces into single braces

Tags: java, regex, dictionary

I want to merge  my output into one hash-map. Even though it is in one hash-map and each time my program enters a loop it each output prints in separate lines inside separate braces. I want it in single braces so I can do further processing....My output gets printed in the following format

```
    {"XXXXXXXXX",9};
    {"YYYYYYYY",65};
    {"BHYTDER",23};
    {"PPPPPP",90};
```

But I want the above output to be printed like this

```
{"XXXXXXXXX"=9,"YYYYYYYY"=65,"BHYTDER"=23,"PPPPPP"=90};
```

I think I can use regular expression. Is there any regular expression for removing closing braces of all sentences and replace it with comma and only add closing braces at the end?

Comment: Try this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295801/merging-multiple-hashmaps

Answer (score 1):

Implement own printing, not relying on the map's toString method:

```
    System.out.print("{");
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
        System.out.print("\""+entry.getKey()+"\"="+entry.getValue());
        if (iter.hasNext()) System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println("}");
```

The example explains how to print a single map. You can have the similar outer loop over maps in some collection, and also call the Iterator.hasNext twice to print comma between elements but not after last element.

This approach allows to print maps as expected even if they share some keys, possibly mapping into different values. We could simply merge all maps into one, but duplicate keys will be discarded, leaving only the last value merged.

Comment: I tested your code and it shows output as

    {"YYYYYYYY"=65, "XXXXXXXXX"=9, "PPPPPP"=90, "BHYTDER"=23}

But I want  my output in the below format

    {YYYYYYYY=65, XXXXXXXXX=9, PPPPPP=90, BHYTDER=23}

Comment: Your own question initially required quotes, and still does at the moment of writing. Remove quotes yourself as an exercise, this looks like a homework.