# Is there a way to chain Lists (or Maps) in a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Having this code:

```
Map<String,Rect> map1 = new HashMap<String,Rect>();
Map<String,Rect> map2 = new HashMap<String,Rect>();
...
for( Rect r: map1.values() ) {
    r.offset(10,10);
}
for( Rect r: map2.values() ) {
    r.offset(10,10);
}
```

If the code inside both loops is the same, is there a simple way to combine the two loops into one loop? (Assume all map keys are different).
I do have some ideas that would help too (like **merging the two maps** into one single map or having a **method** doing the loop with the map as argument), but I wonder if there is something in Java syntax that just allows to chain two similar list and loop through them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610261/is-it-possible-to-merge-iterators-in-java

Comment: Yep, duplicate. Good info on that post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java does not natively support this behaviour.

If you were to use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) then you could do this:

```
for (final Rect rect : Iterables.concat(map1.values(), map2.values())) {

}
```

You could also knock up a quick utility class. I've used varargs here so that the usage is nicer; the downside is that the compiler will throw lots of warnings as generic array creation and varargs methods are unchecked.

```
public class CombinedIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    public static <T> Iterable<T> concat(Iterable<? extends T>... iterables) {
        return new CombinedIterable<T>(iterables);
    }

    private final List<Iterable<? extends T>> iterables;

    private CombinedIterable(Iterable<? extends T>... iterables) {
        this.iterables = Arrays.asList(iterables);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {

            private final Iterator<Iterable<? extends T>> pos = iterables.iterator();
            private Iterator<? extends T> iter = pos.next().iterator();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (pos.hasNext()) {
                    iter = pos.next().iterator();
                }
                return iter.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                return iter.next();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Usage is something like:

```
final List<String> s1 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});
final List<String> s2 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"D", "E", "F"});
final List<String> s3 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"H", "I", "J"});
for (final String s : CombinedIterable.concat(s1, s2, s3)) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And with the magic of `import static`

```
for (final String s : concat(s1, s2, s3)) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

If you're into that sort of thing...

Comment: Shouldn't the `CombinedIterable.concat(s1,s2,s3)` be `CombinedIterable<String>.concat(s1,s2,s3)` ?

Comment: @ilomambo; no. I have used a static factory method pattern to avoid having to specify the type.

Comment: Why not to support the `remove()` method? What are the problems of executing `iter.remove()` instead of throwing the exception?

Comment: @ilomambo no problem, I just didn't. Depending on your use case you may not may not want to allow deletion from concatenated `Iterable`s. Also behaviour is slightly odd if some `Iterable`s in the list support `remove` and some don't.

Comment: One last clarification. If I am not mistaken `CombinedIterable` allows to `concat` iterables that are of different classes too, for example Map and Set.

Comment: @ilomambo what do you mean? The `Iterable` will be of the narrowest class that encapsulates all given `Iterable`s - for example a `CombinedIterable` over an `Iterable<Integer>` and an `Iterable<Long>` would be an `Iterable<Number>`; you would have to provide a type hint however as Java's type inference system is rubbish - `CombinedIterable.<Number>concat(...)`.

Comment: I meant that having `ArrayList<String> a` and `HashSet<String> b` it would fine to do `for( String s: concat(a,b) )`

Comment: @ilomambo why don't you try it? How long would that take you?

Comment: Of course I will, i think your solution is brilliant. I already coded it into my app, just now I am waitng on some other changes before I can compile and try it.

Comment: Just finished testing `CombinedIterable class`. It works as expected, including concatenating collections of different types (`List` and `Set` for example), as long a the collections elements are of compatible types (all Strings for example)

Answer (score 0):

Crate method and call it as many time as you want

```
public void updateOffset(Map<String,Rect> map) {
    for( Rect r: map.values() ) {
        r.offset(10,10);
    }
}
```

and now your code become

```
Map<String,Rect> map1 = new HashMap<String,Rect>();
Map<String,Rect> map2 = new HashMap<String,Rect>();
...
updateOffset(map1);
updateOffset(map2);
```

Combining of map is always restrict you that your map are always having unique keys. So merge only if you are sure that your keys always be unique.

Comment: Thank you, Ashish, this is one of the ideas I presented in my question too. I actually want to know if there is some list chaining syntax in java.

Comment: @ilomambo there in no eact list chaining method. But if you don't waht to do like this you can add all values to List/Set and then perform operation in single iteration

Comment: Thank you again Ashish, that is the other idea (merge) I presented too. I am afraid that possibly the very nature of iterators will prevent chaining of lists, and will have to use one of the other two solutions. Just thought that the code would look more elegant with chaining. Let's wait some hours to see if someone has some new info, if not I will accept your answer.