# Java - how to obtain an interleaved iterator/collection

Tags: java, collections

Let's say we receive strings from 3 producers asynchronously. Once a certain amount of these objects have been received I want to iterate over them in an interleaved manner, that is, if receiving the following strings:

```
"a1" received from A,
"a2" received from A,
"c1" received from C,
"a3" received from A,
"b1" received from B,
"b2" received from B,
```

I'd like the "interleaved" iterator to return the strings as if we were iterating over the following list:

```
List<String> interleavedList = {"a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "c2", "a3"},
```

So far I've created one `List<String>` for each producer, and then I'm "iterating" over all the strings by working with the 3 list iterators (with a `List<Iterator<String>>`). This works fine but I think there is a simpler way... Maybe by directly constructing the interleaved list while receiving the strings? but I don't see which `Collection` or which `Comparator` to use...

Note that I'm not so much interested in creating one list for each producer and then merging the 3 lists in a 4th interleaved list, as this will probably not be time-efficient.

Comment: Can you tell us more about efficiency? E.g. with a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) you can achieve this, however, that would slow down the producers. On the other hand, using the lists as you mentioned is totally time-efficient. It uses up some memory instead.

Comment: You could subclass java.util.Iterator to achieve this. Also see following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610261/is-it-possible-to-merge-iterators-in-java

Comment: if using java 8,have you tried interleave strings in stream ?

Comment: Do the producers finish they job sometime? Can you wait to iterate the final results?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want the list to be sorted, with the number determining the sort first and the letter second.  Java does not have a sorted list, because the nature of lists is that they are not sorted.  However, you could use a sorted set with a custom comparator:

```
SortedSet<String> sortedset = new TreeSet<String>(
        new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String e1, String e2) {
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
                if (num1 > num2) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (num1 < num2) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    String let1 = e1.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
                    String let2 = e2.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
                    return let1.compareTo(let2);
                }
            }
        });
```

When you iterate over this set, you will get the ordering you described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to dump all objects into a `PriorityBlockingQueue` based on the producer-specific index in which they arrive:

```
class Message {
   String data;
   long index;
}

PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>(
  10,
  Comparator.comparing(m -> m.index)
); 

List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>(BATCH_SIZE);
for (;;) {
   for (int i = 0; i < BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
      batch.add(queue.take().data);
   }
   handleBatch(batch);
   batch.clear();
}
```

Note this assumes an infinite queue; if the queue is non-infinite you would have to add some logic to handle the final batch.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your strings to `PriorityQueue<String>` with a custom `Comparator`. In this case your elements will be automatically sorted when you add them.
Here is a [useful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem recently, here is what I came up with (just take from each iterator in turns until all them drain, no sorting):

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class InterleavedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

  static class Node<K> {
    Node<K> next;
    Node<K> prev;
    final K value;

    Node(K value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<K> next) {
      this.next = next;
    }

    public void setPrev(Node<K> prev) {
      this.prev = prev;
    }
  }

  private Node<Iterator<T>> node;

  public InterleavedIterator(Collection<Iterator<T>> iterators) {
    Node<Iterator<T>> prev = null;
    for (Iterator<T> iterator : iterators) {
      if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
        continue;
      }
      Node<Iterator<T>> current = new Node<>(iterator);
      if (prev != null) {
        prev.setNext(current);
        current.setPrev(prev);
      } else {
        node = current;
      }
      prev = current;
    }
    if (prev != null) {
      prev.setNext(node);
      node.setPrev(prev);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return node.value.hasNext();
  }

  @Override
  public T next() {
    T res = node.value.next();
    updateNode();
    return res;
  }

  private void updateNode() {
    Node<Iterator<T>> nextNode = node.next;
    if (node.value.hasNext()) {
      node = nextNode;
    } else if (node != nextNode) {
      node.prev.next = nextNode;
      nextNode.prev = node.prev;
      node = nextNode;
    }
  }
}
```