# Can I wrap multiple Java sorted sets so they look like one?

Tags: java, collections

I have several lists of data that I would like to occasionally treat as one list.

I currently create a new list (`newList`), then loop through the existing lists, and perform `newList.addAll(thisList)`.

This is time consuming, and includes lots of allocations, when I just wish to be able to loop through all the child items.

Instead, is there a way to cosmetically wrap this lists in a parent iterator, and then loop through this?

Comment: Are you asking about lists or sorted sets? The title says one thing and the question body another thing.

Comment: Use `List of ArrayList`.

Comment: The top answer to this question might be what you're searching: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610261/is-it-possible-to-merge-iterators-in-java

Comment: Thanks Rolf, that's a great strategy.  Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class representing list of lists and store references to the lists in it. The list would implement `Iterator`, so that you could iterate over it just like any other `Collection`:

```
public class ListOfLists<U> implements Iterator<U> {

    List<List<U>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

    private int currentList = 0;
    private Iterator<U> currentIter;

    public ListOfLists(List<U>... lists) {
        this.lists.addAll(Arrays.asList(lists));

        currentIter = this.lists.get(0).iterator();
    }

    void add(List<U> list) {
        lists.add(list);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while (currentList < lists.size() - 1 && !currentIter.hasNext()) {
            currentList++;
            currentIter = lists.get(currentList).iterator();
        }

        return currentIter.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public U next() {
        while (currentList < lists.size() - 1 && !currentIter.hasNext()) {
            currentList++;
            currentIter = lists.get(currentList).iterator();
        }

        return currentIter.next();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(5, 7, 9);
        List<Integer> l3 = Arrays.asList(42, 43, 44);

        ListOfLists<Integer> ii = new ListOfLists<>(l1, l2, l3);

        while (ii.hasNext())
            System.out.println(ii.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jdk-8 you can merging multi-iterators simpler by using [Stream#flatMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) & [Stream#iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator--), for example:

```
Iterator<T> all = Stream.of(list1,list2,...,listN).stream()
                                                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                                                  .iterator();
```

*Note*: `flatMap` just iterates all `List`s want to merged, not all of the element in the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rolf-schäuble for the link, this answer provides a great solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488126/92441